# Generating "surrogate data" to calculate error on estimators

Tags: time-series, maximum-likelihood, estimators, uncertainty, surrogate

We have a dataset in the form of a time series $Y_n$.

We assume it follows an underlying parametric distribution $f(n,\beta)$, $\beta$ being the parameters.

From the observed dataset, we get an estimator $\tilde{\beta}$ for the parameters (say from an MLE). I am interested in the uncertainty of this estimator. Of course, there could be a variety of methods, but I am interested in the use of surrogate data as done in this paper: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0048733315001699

Basically, the idea is simple: we generate a bunch of artificial data using the distribution $f$ with parameters $\tilde{\beta}$ (we do a Monte Carlo simulation for those who like complicated words to describe simple things). Those generated data will differ from the original: we then apply our MLE to each of these new surrogate data to obtain new estimations. We obtain this way a distribution of estimated parameters, which can be summarized with whatever suitable metric (e.g. std dev)

Sounds great to me, makes intuitive sense. The only problem is, I can't really find documentation to back up the validity of this method. When searching, I can't get out of a loophole because it seems that all I can find when looking for surrogate data tests are specific tests for the linearity of a system. I could not find a reference that uses surrogate data in this way to calculate uncertainties on estimators.

**Question: Is this surrogate data procedure valid for calculating errors on estimators, and could you point me to sources that discuss/prove it?**

Comment: Sounds like a parametric bootstrap to me.

Comment: @utobi Oh wow, I take it back, apparently parametric bootstrap is just the keyword I was missing. That does seem to be exactly what I'm looking for, and I should have what I need to do further research on my own. Well, that was a swift answer, that makes me feel a little silly for asking, but thanks a lot

Comment: glad to read it helped :-). For completeness, I expanded on an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my comment, what you described seems to be matching with the parametric bootstrap. Very quickly, the bootstrap method comes in two flavours:

(a) parametric

(b) nonparametric.

Very informally, in (b), new data are generated by sampling with replacement from the original data, samples of the same size as the original dataset. On the other hand, in (a) we sample from the parametric model assumed for the data at hand, with the parameter value fixed at the estimate obtained from the original data.

For a complete treatment of the bootstrap, why it works, and when it doesn't work please check Davison and Hinkley's book [Bootstrap Methods and Applications](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511802843).